# Cluster many thousands observations (mixed variable types). Cluster subsample and then classify the rest observations?

Tags: clustering, large-data, mixed-type-data, gower-similarity

I'm trying to run a cluster analysis on a large dataset (70k+ observations to cluster) with mixed variables (numeric, ordinal, binary and nominal). I don't think I can create the distance matrix using SAS over the entire dataset. So, I have tried to run a hierarchical clustering using Gower's distance over a *subsample* of my data. I've got some questions.

1. If the above method (hierarchical clustering of a subsample) is
   appropriate, how can I then score the rest of the observations and
   assign (classify) them to the clusters obtained?
2. If the above method isn't good, what are other recommended
   methods to cluster a large dataset with mixed variables? (Available
   in SAS if possible.)
3. How can I check for correlations/multicolinearity among mixed
   variables? I don't know if running something like PCA or factor
   analysis makes sense with categorical data.

Comment: Please check my editing of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hierarchical clustering in general does not scale well to large data sets. There are some special cases such as SLINK that need only $O(n)$ memory and $O(n^2)$ runtime (naive implementations need $O(n^2)$ memory and $O(n^3)$ runtime). So may need to look into alternative methods such as DBSCAN. DBSCAN will work with arbitrary distance measures; but you will probably not have index acceleration, so it will be $O(n^2)$ runtime, too. But it should still scale to 70k observations; I have ran DBSCAN on 100k years ago. The key is to *not* compute a complete distance matrix, because that needs $O(n^2)$ memory then.

However, *neither* will have an obvious way of classifying new observations. Clustering is just something different than classification. It's about getting a *sketch* of structure in the data to then *analyze* and turn into knowledge. No clustering will ever be perfect, but it may be able to tell you something you did not know before. You should then formalize it in a way that you can make use of it later.

Obviously, an universal approach is to train a classifier on the clusters afterwards.

I don't know what is available in SAS. I believe it only has the most basic methods available, nothing advanced.