# Cluster analysis in SPSS

Tags: self-study, clustering, spss, hierarchical-clustering, two-step-estimation

I started learning cluster analysis (using SPSS) and I need some help in a practical problem.

> Given the following variables:
>   The respondents were asked to indicate the importance of the following factors when buying products and services using a 5-point scale (1=not at all important, 5=very important)
>
> Saving time (x1)
>       Getting bargains (x2)
>       Getting products that aren’t on the high street (x3)
>       Trying new things (x4)
>       Being aware of what companies have to offer (x5)
>       Gender (0=Female; 1=Male)
>       Income
>
> Questions:
>
> 1) Given the levels of measurement, which clustering method would you prefer?
>   Carry out a cluster analysis using this procedure.

As I understand there are both categorical and continuous (income) variables - so the right method is two-step clustering. And we cannot use hierarchical method, correct?

Comment: Likert scales can be considered as scale (interval/ratio) or as ordinal. To treat them as ordinal is more contrite but is less flexible. There is very few options in cluster analysis realm designed specifically for ordinal variables. You might use [Gower similarity](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/15313/3277) and then hierarchical clustering. Or think of them as continuous and use Euclidean distance or whatever you want. The idea to do cluster analysis on a [mixture of variables of different type](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/135767/3277) is not particularly a good idea.

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: @ttnphns Thanks, Can I use Two-Step clustering method in this case?